# Send Apache Access Logs to syslog

Tags: apache-2.2, syslog, aix, ihs

We have IBM HTTP Servers (Based on Apache 2.0) and want to send the **access** logs to syslog. (in addition to error logs which does work)

The config we are using is as follows:

```
ErrorLog "|/HTTPServer/bin/rotatelogs /archive/http/error_log.%Y%m%d 86400 | /usr/bin/logger -t httpd -plocal6.err"
LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %{True-Client-IP}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D \"%{Host}i\" %v" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog "|exec /usr/bin/logger -t ptseelm-ax3004 -i -p local6.notice" combined
```

But the logs entries don't even appear in the local syslog.out

here is what the processes look like:

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
apache  6226000  8388618   0 09:04:01      -  0:00 /HTTPServer/bin/httpd -d /HTTPServer -k start
apache  6750220  8388618   0 09:04:01      -  0:00 /HTTPServer/bin/httpd -d /HTTPServer -k start
apache  7602390  8388618   0 09:04:01      -  0:00 /HTTPServer/bin/httpd -d /HTTPServer -k start
root  8388618        1   0 09:04:01      -  0:00 /HTTPServer/bin/httpd -d /HTTPServer -k start
root  9044038  8388618   0 09:04:01      -  0:00 /usr/bin/logger -t httpd -plocal6.err
```

So there is no logger attached to the child processes... is that the problem? Can someone help me out? :)

We have the following in syslog.conf:

```
local6.*        @somerealipaddress
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the "exec" from CustomLog to match your errorlog version?

Also, is local6.notice being ignored? If you set it to local6.err does it magically start working?

Comment: We had it without exec first, and tried it with now. We have the following in syslog.conf

Comment: local6.*        @xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz <<<<<< real ip of course

Comment: @Seer, it would be better if you could add the syslog config to the question instead of in a comment, it will make it easier for others to read and help you.

Comment: @Regan, the point of having "exec" is to avoid having a dangling shell around, so it's usually a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to instead of piping directly to logger, you would be better off writing to a file and then having a separate process read that file and send it off to syslog.

Many syslog programs, e.g. rsyslog and syslog-ng, can read from a file as well as from /dev/log. Another options is to simply use tail -F and pipe to logger.

Comment: Hmm. We will actually still have a local log too, we are mostly just testing getting into syslog at the moment. From a configuration perspective though, when we are talking about maybe 30-100 HTTP servers, it seemed like it would be nice to have it within the HTTP conf template

Comment: It would, but there's small risk of reduced performance and/or losing log entries. And, in a perfect world, your syslog config should also come from a template and be handled by e.g. puppet... Another issue though is that if you separate the logging from httpd.conf that means you don't have to restart httpd if/when you need to change syslog parameters.

Comment: So you are talking about a script run as a background task? How would you handle log rotation? todays file is called access_log.20131101 for example and yesterdays access_log.20131031 .... bear in mind we are supposed to avoid cronjobs etc

Comment: At my old work, we used syslog-ng. It is very robust with a lot of features. Take a look at http://www.syslog.org/logged/reading-logs-from-a-file-in-syslog-ng/ for a basic example. syslog-ng will simply read from 'access_log' and then in your logrotate you'll need to send syslog-ng a -HUP signal after rotation so it will follow the new 'access_log' inode.

Comment: @Seer As long as log rotation is done by copying the contents to a new file before truncating, there won't be a problem reading from the log file. If, instead, it's done by moving the file and creating a new one with the original name, tail -F will still work (i.e. gnu tail, which will notice the filehandle changing) but other methods may require a HUP or restart.